# Как в sqlite вставить dict (python)

Tags: python, sqlite

Как в sqlite через python полностью засунуть словарь?

Делаю вот так

```
for i in data_dict:
 
    created_at = i['created_at']
    data = (str(i), created_at)

    # Вот тут всё норм, нету никаких слешей
    print(str(i))  # Вывод: {'order_id': 285556196, 'order_number': '30548', posting_number': '305484', 'status': 'delivering', 'cancel_reason_id': 0}
 
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Market (data, created_at) VALUES(?, ?);", (data))
    conn.commit()
```

Потом

```
sql = "SELECT data FROM Market WHERE created_time >= ? AND created_time <= ?;"
cursor.execute(sql, data)
res = cursor.fetchall()
```

И получаю свою строку с кучей слешей

```
print(res)  # Выводит [('{\'order_id\': 285556196, \'order_number\': \'30548\', \'posting_number\': \'305484\', \'status\': \'delivering\', \'cancel_reason_id\': 0}')]
```

Да знаю что так не делается, но у меня dict из сотен разных объектов, делать колонки и записывать туда только элемент не реально, нужно засунуть целиком dict

Comment: Так и вставляйте, если очень нужно, в чем проблема. Обратно через ast.literal_eval загружаете. Хотя по идее лучше использовать json (чтобы не завязываться именно на синтаксис Python словаря). Лишних слешей там на самом деле нет, они отображаются только при выводе строки в кавычках на экран.

Comment: @insolor так не получается делаю [eval(e) for e in res] и получаю ошибку eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Comment: 1 - не используйте eval, используйте ast.literal_eval. 2 - e это похоже tuple из 1 элемента, если это так, то нужно брать первый элемент от него, и его уже конвертирвать в dict.

Comment: @insolor оу, реально помогло, спасибо большое! [ast.literal_eval(i[0]) for i in res]

Comment: Сериализуйте с помощью json'a

Comment: @insolor написал бы ответ чтобы я вопрос отметил решенным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лишних обратных слешей на самом деле в строке нет, они добавляются только при выводе строки в одинарных кавычках, чтобы экранировать внутренние одинарные кавычки (и было понятно, что на внутренней одинарной кавычке строка не заканчивается).

Обратно в словарь конвертируете с помощью `ast.literal_eval` (более безопасная функция чем `eval`, она просто разберет структуру данных в строке, но не будет выполнять любой переданный код).

Пример конвертации (на входе результат запроса в виде списка, где каждая строка - tuple из одного элемента):

```
import ast

res = cursor.fetchall()
dicts = [ast.literal_eval(row[0]) for row in res]
```

Также лучше сохранять словари в базу в виде json, тогда у вас не будет явной привязки к синтаксису Python, можно будет практически на любом языке программирования работать с этими данными. Пример:

```
import json

# Запись в базу
for data in data_dict:
    created_at = data['created_at'] 
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Market (data, created_at) VALUES(?, ?);", (json.dumps(data), created_at)
    conn.commit()

# Чтение из базы
sql = "SELECT data FROM Market WHERE created_time >= ? AND created_time <= ?;"
cursor.execute(sql, (begin_time, end_time))
res = cursor.fetchall()
data = [json.loads(row[0]) for row in res]
```